# Observer pattern implementation uses lots of RAM - how can I find out where and why?

Tags: c++, microcontroller, observer-pattern

I'm in the process of creating a simple implementation of the observer pattern, and found that it uses *a lot* of RAM. I'd like to know why and how I can solve that problem - as it is, my microcontroller's RAM is overfull. These are the classes (and one function) I use:

```
#include <functional>

template<typename... args>
class Connection
{
  public:
    Connection(std::function<void(args...)> func)
      : f(func),
      next(NULL)
    {
    }
    std::function<void(args...)> f; // the function object to execute
    Connection* next; // pointer to next connection in linked list
  private:
    Connection(const Connection&); // no copy construction
    Connection& operator=(const Connection&); // no assignment
};

template<typename... args >
class Signal
{
  public:
    typedef Connection<args...> ConnectionType;
    Signal()
      : connections(NULL)
    {

    }
    void operator()(args... arg) const
    {
      // call all observers
      const ConnectionType* c = connections;
      while(c != NULL)
      {
        c->f(arg...);
        c = c->next;
      }
    }
    void add(ConnectionType* conn) // add an observer
    {
      if (connections == NULL)
      {
        connections = conn;
      }
      else
      {
        lastConnection()->next = conn;
      }
    }
  private:
    Signal(const Signal&); // no copy construction
    Signal& operator=(const Signal&); // no assignment
    ConnectionType* lastConnection() const
    {
      ConnectionType* c = connections;
      if (c == NULL)
      {
        return c;
      }
      while(c->next != NULL)
      {
        c = c->next;
      }
      return c;
    }
    ConnectionType* connections;
};

template<typename Sig, typename Func >
typename Sig::ConnectionType* connect(Sig& sig, Func func)
{
  typedef typename Sig::ConnectionType connection_type;
  connection_type* pConn = new connection_type(func);
  sig.add(pConn);
  return pConn;
}

class Something
{
  public:
  void doSomething(const int& i, const int& offset) const
  {
    // Serial is a USB Virtual Serial device interface
    Serial.print("something ");Serial.println(i + offset);
  }
};
```

Usage is as follows:

```
Signal<const int&> intSig;
Something some;
connect(intSig, std::bind(&Something::doSomething, &some, std::placeholders::_1, 2));
intSig(121); // should print "something 123"
```

Removing the `connect(...)` line decreases RAM usage by about 2 kB, but `sizeof(Connection<const int&>)` is 20. My conclusion is that some part of `functional` is creating a huge vtable or something like that, which is only needed if a connection is actually created.

Compiler is arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8.3
I'm compiling for a Freescale Kinetis mk20dx128 with

```
-Wall
-mthumb
-s
-Os
-mcpu=cortex-m4
-MMD
-std=gnu++0x
-felide-constructors
-fno-exceptions
-fno-rtti
-ffunction-sections
-fdata-sections
-nostdlib
-fpermissive
```

So my questions are:

- How can I track down RAM usage to find out what is using so much of my precious memory?
- What's a good alternative? If it involves not using `std::function` and `std::bind`, is there a more less painless way to do that? It's ok if the solution limits the number of notification arguments to a small value (zero or one is good).

I can not use `boost.signals`.

---

**Why I need *some* flexibility**

My device contains a display and I'm programming simple widgets for that. One example where I would like to use the observer pattern is buttons and hardware button events: When a button is "clicked" (the "Enter" hardware button is pressed), some other widget should change state. The list of widgets has grown over time, as has the number of custom "Action classes" whose `operator()` is called by widgets, but that is not enough when I need multiple things to happen when an event occurs, or when an event is tightly coupled to a value (an index, some digit that changed, ...)

Comment: Make a core dump both ways, run `strings` on them and diff the results.

Comment: A way to track stack/globally allocated data sections is to have a look at the linker map output, or results from nm. For profiling runtime memory usage (allocated from heap), a tool like valgrind might be useful.

Comment: Comparing the map outputs sounds doable and useful. I have not yet found the culprit, though... @n.m. "a lot" is 2 kB of 16 kB available memory. If that doesn't increase when I add more signals and connections, I might get away with a bigger mcu.

Comment: Well, almost allways dynamic arrays (i.e. `std::vector`) perform far better than linked lists: They use only `sizeof(T)` to store each element (instead of your `sizeof(T) + sizeof(Node*) + Heap Metadata`), and are much more fast due to its cache ussage compared to linked lists.

Comment: I suggest you to have a `std::vector` of callbacks instead of this kind of linked list.

Comment: I'm using this kind of linked list because I don't know how much space is reserved for a std::vector. I also don't need random access, so the singly linked list concept is enough. Elements are only inserted during startup, the whole application is more or less static after that.

Answer (score 1):

`std::function` is way overkill for such a platform.

I strongly suspect that on this platform you won't need multiple active signals. So, make a template class `SignalParam<args...>` that keeps the current parameters. this means that all observers can have signature `void()`, and you can store just a plain function pointer.

Similarly, `bind` parameters are best stored in another singleton.

While you should keep `Connection` and `Signal` templated for type safety, offload all work to a common base class. This means you won't have as many copies of identical functions.

BTW, it's easier to `add` a new connection to the front of the list: `conn->next = connections; connections = conn;`. Saves a list walk.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Giving all observers a `void(void)` signature sounds ok, I can move complexity into observers then. I'm not too familiar with `bind` and storing those parameters in singletons, how would I do that? If it's ok for you, we could chat a bit about your suggestions?

Comment: Regarding `SignalParam<args...>`: It took a while until I got behind this idea. `SignalParam<args...>` is specialized for each argument list and contains a static set of parameters that match the arguments. This means that I can set the appropriate signal parameters before calling all observers, and they in turn examine the signal parameters instead of getting them passed as "real" arguments. Is that what you suggested?

Comment: This seemed to be a good idea once I understood it, _but_: Should I decide to "chain" signals (one signal triggers another one with the same parameters, but different values), the template approach would break.

Comment: @Christoph: Yes. Developing for small systems is all about trade-offs. E.g. I know that sacrificing `std::function` loses flexibility, but it will save space. Simple reason: there's space needed for the type erasure.

Comment: I've created a simple delegate class template that seems to work. I only tested it on my PC - not the target system - but it seems to work as intended: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47098/delegate-and-observer-pattern-implementation-for-an-embedded-system As far as I can tell, it will allow for more chained signals and signal parameters than I will ever need.